# Browser keyboard refresh shortcut for Android 2.3.7?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to know if there is any way to associate a keyboard shortcut for refreshing a webpage in Android with physical keyboard version 2.3.7.

Answer (score 1):

There are several interesting browser shortcuts available:

```
Menu + J: Back
Menu + K: Forward
Menu + R: Refresh active page
Menu + F: Find
Menu + B: Open bookmarks
Menu + H: Browsing history
Menu + S: Open browser settings
Menu + I: Zoom in
Menu + O: Zoom out
```

(Source: [Android Browser keyboard shortcuts](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/13918-android-browser-keyboard-shortcuts))